# Using useFuture conditionally

Tags: flutter, flutter-hooks

I've been working with flutter-hooks' *useFuture* method, but I need to use it conditionally (based on user-input in this case). I've found this approach, but I need to know if there is a better way:

Storing what data is selected using *useState*, and if there is some data selected, change the future from null to the actual future. Example code:

```
final selected = useState<int>(null);
final future = useMemoizedFuture(() => selected.value != null ? http.get("someapi") : null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the data as the keys of the memoizer. Then add the conditions for working with the future in the code where you need it, not in the hooks themselves.

```
final selectedIndex = useState<int?>(null);
final someFuture = useMemoizedFuture(() => http.get("someapi"), [useSelected.value]);
```